# How to read logcat written through my application in all android os

Tags: android, android-logcat

I need to capture all the logs written through my application. I know from Jetllybean OS we can read need only our application log. But when I tried by using command "logcat -d" using exec method by application and  I did not get any data.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,

Saravanakumar

Comment: Do you want to do this pro grammatically? If not, you go do this in the command line 'adb logcat -s "<your logcat tag>" >> logcat.txt'

Comment: Thanks Wangyif2. Yes. I want to capture the log programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the example that I was playing around with before that will generate a log text file in local storage:

```
private static String generateLogcatLogCommond = "logcat -d > /sdcard/IssueReport/log.txt";

public static String generateLogcatLog() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        File issueReport = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "IssueReport");
        if (!issueReport.exists())
            issueReport.mkdir();
        File logFile = new File(issueReport,"log.txt");
        logFile.createNewFile();

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/sh -");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(generateLogcatLogCommond);

        logLocation = "/sdcard/IssueReport/log.txt";
        Log.d("Client", logLocation);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return logLocation;
}
```

What the above code is doing is using 'sh' to run 'logcat -d' command and save it as a file locally. This will get ALL the logcat log. For you, you can change that to 'logcat -s ""' and it will save all logcat log of your application to a file.

Comment: Is is easy to get these logs as string and use it?

And what is the command "/system/bin/sh -" doing here.. I saw only "logcat -d" command only.

And this will capture all type of logs that is written in Log.d, Log.i or any particular type only.

Comment: What the above code is doing is using 'sh' to run 'logcat -d' command and save it as a file locally. This will get ALL the logcat log. For you, you can change that to 'logcat -s "<TAG>"' and it will save all logcat log of your application to a file.

Comment: Android OS is linux based, in the /system/bin you will find all the common linux based tools, such as sh, which you can use to run other commands such as logcat, or pm etc..

Comment: Ok thank you wangyif2. I will try that. But I want to read logs as string.

Comment: you can do simple file I/O, and use readline to read each line of file as a string. I would say this is rather a work-around, if you could describe what you want to do in detail in the original post I could suggest something better.

Comment: Yes. I know how to read from file but I just to know whether we can read log directly in to string instead of writing into file and read it again.

Comment: Sure, you can get the outputStream from the Process that 'sh' started

Comment: ok sure. i will do some work on this and come to you. thanks wangyif2

Comment: I got it to work. Is it possible to get logcat data with time also?

Comment: You can just log the time in you Log.i

Comment: Did you manage to read the logcat output from the InputStream?  Mine just seems to hang and never write anything.